# Lighting not working on iOS device with fpc

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, 2d

i have 1 first person controller in my game.

I set light on camera and light falls on game scene **every thing seems lightingup just fpc seems black...**

Here is a photo of that...

in unity editer it fpc seems lightedup but while running code in ios devices it looks black..

render setting is ok..

other object are affected with that light just fpc wont which i want....

i am using unity3.5

[image]
[image]

Comment: How is the lighting applied to your character?  From your description the most likely culprit is a failing shader but it's hard to say without seeing any code.